# Python-docx: adding shapes (rectangle)

Tags: python, shapes, python-docx

I want to add a shape like in the picture [example of the shape I want -- > https://i.stack.imgur.com/k96I2.png) to my python-docx file but cannot find a solution. It's a simple rectangle but needs to be manipulated via color, height and width and also thickness of lines and the fill.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The python-docx library affords the capacity to implement table borders, serving as an effective workaround for adding borders as in your image.

Here is a full demo:

```
    from docx import Document
    from docx.shared import Pt
    from docx.enum.text import WD_PARAGRAPH_ALIGNMENT
    from docx.oxml import OxmlElement
    from docx.oxml.ns import qn
    
    doc = Document()
    
    table = doc.add_table(rows=1, cols=1)
    
    table.autofit = False
    table.columns[0].width = Pt(442)
    table.rows[0].height = Pt(500) 
    
    cell = table.cell(0, 0)
    tc_pr = cell._element.get_or_add_tcPr()
    borders = OxmlElement('w:tcBorders')
    tc_pr.append(borders)
    
    for border_type in ['top', 'left', 'bottom', 'right']:
        border_elm = OxmlElement(f'w:{border_type}')
        border_elm.set(qn('w:val'), 'single')
        border_elm.set(qn('w:sz'), '24')
        border_elm.set(qn('w:space'), '0')
        border_elm.set(qn('w:color'), 'FF0000')
        borders.append(border_elm)
    
    paragraph = table.cell(0, 0).add_paragraph()
    run = paragraph.add_run('Hello, World!')
    
    paragraph.alignment = WD_PARAGRAPH_ALIGNMENT.CENTER
    
    for _ in range(5):
        doc.add_paragraph()
    
    doc.save('hello_world.docx')
```

Here  you can adjust width and height:

```
    table.columns[0].width = Pt(442)
    table.rows[0].height = Pt(500)
```

You can adjust the thickness of the border by changing the value of the 'w:sz' attribute. This attribute refers to the size of the border. In the XML for DOCX, the size is given in eighths of a point. So if you want a 4 point border, you would use '32' (since 4*8 = 32).

I have to point out that I've tested this code in libre-office. Also I've added 5 empty paragraphs on the bottom, you can remove them or adjust them as needed.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! It was very helpful and i was able to accomplich what i wanted! Thanks!!